# Solvability of a variant Fermat equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If
$p$
is an odd prime,
are there any pairwise coprime integers
$a, b, c > 0$
such that
$$(a-b+c)^{p} + (a+b-c)^{p} = (a+b+c)^{p}$$
[a proof without Fermat's last theorem]

Comment: Maybe since in a comment you say so, the condition to prove it without use of Fermat's Last Theorem should be included in the question.

Comment: Sorry, may I know what it means by the symbol ``tilde over the equal sign''? A first guess: congruence relation, is it true?

Comment: @user51615: where did you see this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fermat's Last Theorem states that there are no non-trivial (i.e. $x,y,z\neq 0$) positive integer solutions to $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for $n\geq 3$.  The first odd prime is 3, so there are no solutions to your equation.

The only possibilities are for at least one of $a-b+c$, $a+b-c$, or $a+b+c$ to be non-positive.  If one is zero, all must be zero, but $a+b+c>0$ since $a,b,c>0$.

Thus, we need only check the case when some of them are negative. Since $a,b,c>0$, it follows that $a+b+c>0$.  Thus, with $x=a-b+c$, $y=a+b-c$ and $z=a+b+c$, we know that $z^p>0$.  Thus, it cannot be that both $x,y<0$ as $x^p,y^p<0$ and $x^p+y^p<0<z^p$.  Thus, only one of $x$ or $y$ may be negative.  Suppose without $x<0$.  Then $y^p=(-x)^p+z^p$ contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem.  Similarly, if $y<0$, then $x^p=(-y)^p+z^p$, again giving us a contradiction.

For this reason, there can be no solutions.

Comment: "If the former" should begin $a>b-c$...

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Comment: Still there must be contradictions in these cases, it seems.

Comment: I feel there should as well, but for now I'm failing to correct the issues...

Comment: All non-zero contradicts FLT. So suppose $a+b-c=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I thought FLT only applied to triples of *positive* integers?

Comment: You can move a negative to the other side.

Comment: Ah, very true, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: did you use coprimeness ?

Comment: Thank you all so much. And sorry for not to specify it correctly, I am really seeking for a proof not using Fermat's last theorem! For, I myself have carried out a likewise proof.

Comment: @mesel No, just that they were all positive.

Comment: @mesel Even without using coprimeness, the contradiction suggested by Andre goes through. That is, either of $a+b-c=0$ or $a-b+c=0$ lead to contradictions, without coprimeness needed.

Comment: @user51615 Ah, you should add that to your question statement, since other answerers likely won't read through all of these comments.  Best of luck

Comment: @Hayden: I think you should use coprimeness so that you should avoid fermat's theorem as it is so strong.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of dealing with the variant Fermat equation **without** solving the Fermat problem is not achievable. Hayden has shown that if the variant equation has a solution with $a$, $b$, $c$ positive, then the original Fermat equation has a non-trivial solution. We show that if the variant equation has no positive solution, then the Fermat equation has no non-trivial solution.

Suppose to the contrary that $x^p+y^p=z^p$, with $x$, $y$, and $z$ positive.
Set $a-b+c=2x$, $a+b-c=2y$, $a+b+c=2z$. Then $a=x+y$, $b=z-x$  and $c=z-y$. If they happen not to be pairwise relatively prime, divide each by $\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: $(m+n)^p\equiv m^p+n^p \ mod \ p$, when use this we will get $a+b\equiv c \ mod \ p$, I think it may be used for solving question without using fermats theorem

Comment: So if one proves what posed then one proves Fermat's last theorem; sounds attractive

Comment: The negative view is that the statement is FLT in (light) disguise.